# How can i do the same thing using For loops instead of while?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I need to modify the program so that for all values of k that are larger than or equal to 0, the program works as it did before, but for all values of k less than 0, the program displays, k, k-1, k-2, … 0. You can only use for loops.
 So my code is this, using while loops,

```
     while (i != k && k > 0) {
         i = i + 1;
         System.out.println(i);
     }
     while (k <= 0) {
         System.out.println(k);
         k = k + 1;
     }
```

I successfully did it for the positive numbers, but I am having issues with negatives.

here is the for loop i wrote for the positives

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i = i + 1) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

please help!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle documentation for [The `for` Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) says (in part)

> The for statement provides a compact way to iterate over a range of values. Programmers often refer to it as the "for loop" because of the way in which it repeatedly loops until a particular condition is satisfied. The general form of the for statement can be expressed as follows:
>
> ```
>  for (initialization; termination; increment) {
>      statement(s)
>  }
> ```
>
> When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:
>
> - The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
> - When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
> - The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or decrement a value.

**tl;dr** you could do something like

```
for (; i != k && k > 0;) {
    System.out.println(++i);
}
for (; k <= 0; k++) {
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! You are right, I am going to try that and see if it works for me.